# After install Wordpress via FishPig

Tags: magento2, wordpress, integration

After install wordpress and added DB for wordpress I have error:

```
The FishPig WordPress theme is installed but is not active. Please login to the WordPress Admin and enable it.
```

And i can't use wordpress pages because on pages i have [image]

How to fix it? Please, help me)

Comment: This portal is for only Magento so please ask Magento related queries.

Comment: https://magefan.com/magento2-blog-extension

Answer (score 0):

You should login WordPress before and active theme fishpig in list theme. It's work for me..
Good luck to you

Answer (score 0):

After investigate and I see that, you need to add this row to wordpress options table:

option_name / option_value

fishpig-theme-hash / 5aa63982d19859c539369b7d771c654c

fishpig wp use fishpig-theme-hash to check version of theme. If this row doesn't have in wp options table, fishpig wp will show this exception.